# Threads can only be started once in Django Channels

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I created a simple Django Channels consumer that should connects to an external source, retrieve data and send it to the client. So, the user opens the page > the consumer connects to the external service and gets the data > the data is sent to the websocket.

Here is my code:

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer, AsyncConsumer, AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer

from binance.client import Client
import json
from binance.websockets import BinanceSocketManager
import time
import asyncio

client = Client('', '')

trades = client.get_recent_trades(symbol='BNBBTC')
bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
class EchoConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):


    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()
        await self.send_json('test')


        bm.start_trade_socket('BNBBTC', self.process_message)
        bm.start()


    def process_message(self, message):
        JSON1 = json.dumps(message)
        JSON2 = json.loads(JSON1)

        #define variables
        Rate = JSON2['p']
        Quantity = JSON2['q']
        Symbol = JSON2['s']
        Order = JSON2['m']

        asyncio.create_task(self.send_json(Rate))
        print(Rate)
```

This code works when i open one page; if i try to open a new window with a new account, though, it will throw the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Heroku\github\master\myapp\consumers.py", line 54, in connect
    bm.start()
  File "C:\Users\User\lib\threading.py", line 843, in start
    raise RuntimeError("threads can only be started once")
  threads can only be started once
```

I'm new to Channels, so this is a noob question, but how can i fix this problem? What i wanted to do was: user opens the page and gets the data, another user opens the page and gets the data; is there no way to do that? Or am i simply misunderstanding how Django Channels and websockets works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need a secondary thread ?

```
class EchoConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):

    symbol = ''

    async def connect(self):
        self.symbol = 'BNBBTC'
        # or, more probably, retrieve the value for "symbol" from query_string
        # so the client can specify which symbol he's interested into:
        #    socket = new WebSocket("ws://.../?symbol=BNBBTC");
        await self.accept()

    def process_message(self, message):
        # PSEUDO-CODE BELOW !
        if self.symbol == message['symbol']:
            await self.send({
                'type': 'websocket.send',
                'text': json.dumps(message),
            })
```

For extra flexibility, you might also accept al list of symbols from the client, instead:

```
//HTML
socket = new WebSocket("ws://.../?symbols=XXX,YYY,ZZZ");
```

then (in the consumer):

```
class EchoConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):

    symbols = []

    async def connect(self):
        # here we need to parse "?symbols=XXX,YYY,ZZZ" ...
        # the code below has been stolen from another project of mine and should be suitably adapted
        params = urllib.parse.parse_qs(self.scope.get('query_string', b'').decode('utf-8'))
        try:
            self.symbols = json.loads(params.get('symbols', ['[]'])[0])
        except:
            self.symbols = []

    def process_message(self, message):
        if message['symbol'] in self.symbols:
            ...
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211325/discussion-on-answer-by-mario-orlandi-threads-can-only-be-started-once-in-django).

Comment: @Mario Orlandi I probably solved the problem!! Here is what i did: i created two consumers on my Django Channels app, one is used to subscribe the users whenever a page is opened, so if user opens the market 'BTCUSD', the user is subscribed to the group 'BTCUSD'. The other consumer only receives data from Django Collector, for every trade that it receives from Django collector, it reads the name of the trade and broadcasts it to the right group!

Comment: Nice. However, I do not understand the need for the second consumer.The Django Collector could probably broadcast directly to the right group by itself

Comment: @MarioOrlandi the need for the second consumer comes from the fact that data collector is hosted on another server, so it can't send the data straight to my Django Channels groups, since Django is hosted on a different server. I'm planning to move data collector to Django, so that i can use it as a management command and in that case i will do like you said!

Answer (score 1):

I'm no Django developer, but if I understand correctly, the function `connect` is being called more than once-- and `bm.start` references the same thread most likely made in `bm.start_trade_socket` (or somewhere else in connect). In conclusion, when `bm.start` is called, a thread is started, and when it is done again, you get that error.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what you said; unfortunately my knowledge of asynchronous code and websockets is still small, so i thought that the consumer would send the data to every user

Answer (score 1):

Here start() Start the thread’s activity.

It should be called at most once per thread object. You have made a global object of BinanceSocketManager as "bm".

It will always raise a RuntimeError if called more than once on the same thread object.

Please refer the below mentioned code, it may help you

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer, AsyncConsumer, AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer

from binance.client import Client
import json
from binance.websockets import BinanceSocketManager
import time
import asyncio


class EchoConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    client = Client('', '')

    trades = client.get_recent_trades(symbol='BNBBTC')
    bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)

    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()
        await self.send_json('test')


        self.bm.start_trade_socket('BNBBTC', self.process_message)
        self.bm.start()


    def process_message(self, message):
        JSON1 = json.dumps(message)
        JSON2 = json.loads(JSON1)

        #define variables
        Rate = JSON2['p']
        Quantity = JSON2['q']
        Symbol = JSON2['s']
        Order = JSON2['m']

        asyncio.create_task(self.send_json(Rate))
        print(Rate)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! I tried this, but i'm getting the same error!